# I am getting 404 not found for download a PDF on my Azure app but works locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, pdf, http-status-code-404

I am currently running ASPNET Core MVC app on an Azure server (.net core 3.1), and I am getting 404 when trying to download a PDF file. This works perfectly fine locally but gets 404 when I publish to Azure.

I have no problems downloading a CSV file (whether locally or Azure).

```
// Works locally and in Azure
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadCSV()
{
    var report = await _basicCsvGameReportService.CreateReportAsync();
    return File(report, "text/csv", "relatorio.csv");
}

// Works locally only
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadPDF()
{
    var report = await _basicPdfGameReportService.CreateReportAsync();
    return File(report, "application/pdf", "relatorio.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Azure app service to host your ASPNET Core MVC app?

Comment: Yes @StanleyGong I am using it